# iOS Location Services asks on app open

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

Just trying to add location services to my app (in ObjC). I only want the permissions prompt to appear when I am about to use it, however the prompt appears when I first open the app.

My impression was that the prompt would only appear when `startUpdatingLocation` was called on the `CLLocationManager` object. However this is only called in my app on certain ViewControllers (definitely not my first view controller).

Interestingly this issue only appears in iOS8, it's fine in iOS7. Anyone had a similar issue? Or have any idea what else could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you add the code for CLLocationManager? Is it in app delegate right on launch?

Comment: @SamB Thanks for replying. No, there's no mention of CLLocationManager except in my `SearchViewController`, which is where I do my location based search.

Comment: @LouisTur `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`. This is required, right?

Comment: see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing where you had placed your code, the way I would approach this issue is

- Create a method that asks for location access i.e. - (void) findLocationAsk
- Now don't call this method right on app launch as you didn't want that behavior
- Call this method in your view controller
- You can call it in your viewDidLoad or as a button action or fire it as a timer.

This should take care of your prompt on app launch

**UPDATE:**
Your app will prompt for location access right on startup on iOS 8. This is because the "Required background modes" required key is detected in plist file. The only thing you can do is make that message more descriptive as to why you need access. Add this key and description pair to your plist file and add whatever explanation text you like in it

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
Please grant this app access to your location incase of failed login attempts are detected and you want to know who it was

Comment: This is logical thinking and something I have tried in a few of my apps however iOS8 doesn't work this way for some illogical reason. It forces you the notification on the applicable class that contains CLLocationManager.

Comment: @SASmith Just tested this on a new test iOS 8 app and you are right.

Comment: It's quite terrible really. I have no idea why it was changed.

Comment: So to confirm, there is no way to ask for permissions at a later time? Only on start up??

Answer (score 2):

iOS 8 changes how location services are handled, and it also means that if you're supporting older versions of the OS you potentially need to do some extra coding. For an wonderfully detailed look at the entire process, checkout [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/)

Prior to iOS 8, yes calling `startUpdatingLocation` would prompt the user for permission. Though now requesting permission and starting the location updates are separate and you'll need to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

Not only that, but in iOS8 you need to explicitly add two plist keys and then define their values: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, which are strings that will show up in the alert that notifies users that your app is requesting location information.

But seriously, check out the link. It's phenomenal at explaining this all, far better than I could summarize here.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've read that before and it's very helpful. Unfortunately I've done all that (asked for perms separately in iOS8) and I'm still having the issue. As soon as the app sees `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in the plist, it prompts. Very annoying

Comment: when do you call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`? are you implementing the delegate method `didChangeAuthorizationStatus`? same results after you clean and clear derived data?

Comment: When a user clicks a button, I alert asking if they would like to give permission. If so, I run `if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
                [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` as suggested in your link.